# How achieve the effect of having a different max_check_attempts values for WARNING and CRITIAL states Nagios?

Tags: nagios

For example, I want that when service X check results in a *WARNING* state, it send a notification right away (**max_check_attempts=1**), but if the check results is *CRITICAL* (**max_check_attempts=3**), it check twice time more before send the notification. My requirement come from the fact that I configure different *Nagios contacts* for CRITICAL and WARNING.

My goal is avoid some kind of *Nagios contacts* receive a notification so soon (if is a Notif related to a WARNING state), still, I need other *contacts* get informed about a serious  problem (CRITICAL state) asap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the functionality you are looking for you want to use (host/[service)escalations](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#serviceescalation).

```
max_check_attempts
```

is a function of the service/host check itself, not if it's in a warning or critical state.

Comment: [Nagios escalation system](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/escalations.html) don't allow define who is notified and when taking in consideration what the status is, if is CRITICAL or if is WARNING, and that is what I need. Any body know how achieve that?

Comment: BTW, I know that *max_check_attempts* is conf parameter that is not related to the service/host state, but what I wanted achieve is easily described that way... supposing that *max_check_attempts* could be defined by states (CRITICAL/WARNING), so my questions is related to how achieve such effect, that of course, can't be achieve using *max_check_attempts* per state, cos such thing not exist and my questions would have been trivial/stupid ;)

Comment: It does, please look at the escalation_options option. You can create 2 escalations, both with first notification set to 1, one that's for "w" and the other for "c".